# PersistenceUnit initialization without classloading?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

when I try to initiate following persistence unit

```
<persistence-unit name="Cibet" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>java:/CibetDS</jta-data-source>
  <jar-file>lib/cibet-1.5.jar</jar-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

in JBoss-eap-6.1 I get:

```
ERROR 18:32:24,158 -MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."cibetArq1.war#Cibet": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."cibetArq1.war#Cibet": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/shiro/mgt/DefaultSecurityManager
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/shiro/mgt/DefaultSecurityManager
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:635)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.TempClassLoader.findClass(TempClassLoader.java:79)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:491)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:866)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:599)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:91)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
```

The missing class is used in one class like this:

```
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.Realm;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;

public class CibetSecurityManager extends DefaultSecurityManager {
...
```

However, CibetSecurityManager is optional and is only used by the application if Shiro libs are really on the classpath. If Shiro is not in the classpath, the classloader should never try to load it. 
Now it seems the JBoss (or Hibernate, not sure) PersistenceUnit initialising process tries to load ALL classes that it finds in the jar.

Question: Can I somehow tell JBoss/Hibernate to find the @Entity annotated classes without classloading all classes in the jar? In Tomee/OpenJpa this works without problem

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, you can explicitly list all your entity classes in your persistence.xml by adding:

```
<class>my.example.package.ExampleEntity</class>
...
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Which should avoid the entity scanning. I'll have a look at the sources to see if you can turn this around and list classes *not* to scan.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I use as workaround. But as cibet.jar is a framework lib, I don't want to expose too much internals to the users and make it as easy to handle as possible.